# .htaccess redirect with exceptions

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect all visits to a specific sub-folder with a few exceptions.

This is the URL I am trying to redirect:

- www.example.com/my-sub-folder/

I would like any hits to anything under that URL to be redirected to the following URL:

- www.example.com/news/category/my-new-sub-folder/

Except, I don't want to redirect these URLs:

- www.example.com/my-sub-folder/my-special-folder/.*
- www.example.com/my-sub-folder/wp-admin/.*

I have tried to do the following within my .htaccess file but it does not seem to deal with the exceptions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-sub-folder/my-special-folder(/.*)?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-sub-folder/wp-admin(/.*)?$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-sub-folder(/.*)?$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news/category/my-new-sub-folder/ [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: https://amitoverflow.com/2021/05/01/redirect-domain-with-exception/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `OR` in the conditions you need to include all the conditions. Try this rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-sub-folder/my-special-folder/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-sub-folder/wp-admin/? [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-sub-folder/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news/category/my-new-sub-folder/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I forgot to ask, what does the ? do at the end of the RewriteCond

Comment: It makes the `/` optional on the directory so if you have it or not, the condition will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Well you tagged it Wordpress, so you could use the Wordpress rewrite API instead of manually adding htaccess rules. Here is the codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule Then put the rules in a plugin or your theme's functions.php file.