# htaccess redirect all links except base url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect all links from my site except the home url to subdirectory.

Example:
`www.example.com` should remain `www.example.com`
`www.example.com/someurl` should redirect to `www.example.com/sub/someurl`
`www.example.com/someurl/anothermore` should redirect to `www.example.com/sub/someurl/anothermore`

Edit: I am currently working on a subdirectory so currently its `www.example.com/main/someurl` to redirect to `www.example.com/main/sub/someurl`

Comment: Please add your research results - what did you find out, what did you try? Which website did you consult?

Comment: And did you check stackoverflow posts for answers, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099441/htaccess-redirect-with-exceptions?rq=1 ?

Comment: something like `RewriteRule ^https://www.example.com(?!.*sub) https://www.example.com/sub$1 [L,NE,R=301]`   - which will turn : `https://www.example.com/test/lars/example` into `https://www.example.com/sub/test/lars/example`

Comment: @Stender didn't work bro.

Comment: I am currently working on a subdomain so currently its `www.example.com/main/someurl` to redirect to `www.example.com/main/sub/someurl`

Comment: you didn't write anything about `/main/` in the question?

Comment: so it should be `^https://www.example.com/main/(?!.*sub) https://www.example.com/main/sub$1 [L,NE,R=301]` right?

Comment: @Stender tried that. didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect everything to the `/sub` subdirectory, except the root then you can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file in the document root using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/
RewriteRule !^(index\.php)?$ /sub%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The above states that if the request is not `/` (or `/index.php`) and does not start `/sub/` (the `RewriteCond` directive) then redirect to `/sub/<suburl>`.

> Edit: I am currently working on a **subdomain** so currently its `www.example.com/main/someurl` to redirect to `www.example.com/main/sub/someurl`

That's a subdirectory, not a "subdomain". (?)

If this is the case then move these directives to a `/main/.htaccess` file and change them to read:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main/(index\.php)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main/sub/
RewriteRule (.*) /main/sub/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: it's redirecting now but `main` is written twice (before and after `sub`): `www.example.com/main/sub/main/someurl`

Comment: seems that `/main` is included in `{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: Sorry, yes, my bad, the `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path so it does indeed contain `/main` - I've fixed the second example. It doesn't matter what `RewriteBase` is set to here - it's not used.

Comment: Thanks alot @MrWhite, could you also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212773/htaccess-change-url-first-slash-to-underscore-on-certain-condition please.