# htaccess merge 2 segments with underscore

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to merge 2 segments into 1 using underscore.

Example:
`http://example.com/main/id_id/someurl`
should point to
`http://example.com/main/id/id/someurl`

What I got so far as I understand htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /main/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/main/id_id(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/main/id/id%1 [L]
```

But accessing `http://example.com/main/id_id` just redirects to `http://example.com/main/id/id`. I'm wondering why it is redirecting since I didn't use `R` flag

Also as simple as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /main/
RewriteRule ^main/id_id$ /main/id/id/ [L]
```

Should work, but it's not. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I think this is a wordpress thing. I can mask direct access to directories like images but I cannot mask pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But accessing `http://example.com/main/id_id` just redirects to `http://example.com/main/id/id`. I'm wondering why it is redirecting since I didn't use `R` flag.

If you specify an absolute URL (ie. scheme + Hostname) in the `RewriteRule` *substitiution* then Apache will implicitly trigger an external (302) redirect, regardless of whether you've explicitly included the `R` flag or not.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^main/id_id$ /main/id/id/ [L]
> ```
>
> Should work, but it's not.

WordPress routes the URL based on the initial request URL (ie. the 
 value of the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP superglobal), not the rewritten URL. So, yes, this is a "WordPress thing". You would need to create an additional "route" for this URL (not rewrite it). However, this potentially creates issues with duplicate content etc.

However, if you are changing an existing URL that has perhaps been linked to and indexed by search engines then this arguably should be a 301 external redirect and not an internal rewrite.

---

> ```
> RewriteBase /main/
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/main/id_id(.*)$
> RewriteRule .* http://example.com/main/id/id%1 [L]
> ```

This can be simplified to a single directive:

```
RewriteRule ^main/id_id(.*) /main/id/id$1 [R,L]
```

The `RewriteBase` directive is not doing anything here. The `RewriteBase` directive simply states the URL-path that should be used for *relative* path substitutions.

Comment: Ok, in short - not possible. But can it be done using [P] Proxy flag? (at this point, i could care less about SEO)

Comment: Possibly, although mod_proxy may require additional server-side configuration. This should really be done within WordPress itself. See [How to create custom URL routes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes), [Rewrite API/add rewrite rule (WordPress docs)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) and [WP_Route — A simple way to make custom routes in WordPress](https://medium.com/@AnthonyBudd/wp-route-a-simple-way-to-make-custom-routes-in-wordpress-5ab1b3063115)